# how to boot a windows 10 computer without using a M.S. password or internet connection

Tags: internet, connection

I am ending my Internet connection with Comcast.  It is too expensive.  I want to continue to use Windows 10 and my hard drive files on both my laptop and desktop along with MS Word and other applications.  I am 77 years old and hope someone can help me.

Comment: [Simply disconnect your Microsoft Account from within the Settings application.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-or-remove-accounts-on-your-pc-104dc19f-6430-4b49-6a2b-e4dbd1dcdf32 ) You will be prompted for a profile name and will automatically be logged out of your profile.  The process to disconnect your Microsoft Account from your local Windows profile otherwise will be seamless

Comment: Windows (7, 8 and 10 and now only Windows 10) update the second Tuesday of each month and does "feature" updates once or twice a year and interim quarterly updates.  If you use an Office Subscription, it updates 15 or 20 times a year. Can someone nearby you help you with a lower cost internet subscription?  It will be very difficult to manage without Internet. If you wish to try, use this article to convert your Microsoft Account to Local. You must do this.   https://www.windowscentral.com/how-switch-local-account-microsoft-account-windows-10

Comment: The author will be able use their computer offline without an issue.  Updating Windows is unnecessary if the machine isn’t online. Most of my Windows machines at work are connected to an offline closed system that are updated entirely offline manually with extensive testing.  They all work flawlessly.

Comment: In two years or so the version goes out of support and then Windows will complain. So at some point, all Windows needs to update